# Why does my squared loss becomes negative in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I meet a really strange problem that my squared loss becomes negative. Here's my code.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from models.vgg16 import VGG16_fixed
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
from scipy.misc import imsave
from models.generative_model_v2 import gen_model_v2
from scripts.image_process import *
from scripts.utils_func import *
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug

import tensorflow as tf
import os
import time

# configure gpu usage
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))  # pass gpu setting to Keras

# set learning phase, or batch norm won't work
K.set_learning_phase(1)

# dataset setting
width, height = 256, 256
coco_img_path = '../../dataset/coco/images/train2014/'
sl_img_path = './images/style/'

# a trade-off coefficient between content loss and style loss, which is multiplied with style loss
alpha = 1

# create placeholders for input images
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
    content_img_shape = [width, height, 3]
    style_img_shape = [width, height, 3]
else:
    content_img_shape = [3, width, height]
    style_img_shape = [3, width, height]

with tf.name_scope('input'):
    content_img = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32',
                                 shape=(None, content_img_shape[0], content_img_shape[1], content_img_shape[2]),
                                 name='content_img')
    style_img = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32',
                               shape=(None, style_img_shape[0], style_img_shape[1], style_img_shape[2]),
                               name='style_img')

# load model
main_model, outputs = gen_model_v2(input_content_tensor=content_img, input_style_tensor=style_img)
concact_input = K.concatenate([content_img,
                               outputs,
                               style_img], axis=0)
vgg16_model = VGG16_fixed(input_tensor=concact_input,
                          weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# get the symbolic outputs of each "key" layer (we gave them unique names).
vgg16_outputs_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer.output) for layer in vgg16_model.layers])

# get relevant layers
content_feature_layers = 'block3_conv3'
style_feature_layers = ['block1_conv2', 'block2_conv2',
                        'block3_conv3', 'block4_conv3']

# content loss
ct_loss = K.variable(0.)
layer_features = vgg16_outputs_dict[content_feature_layers]
content_img_features = layer_features[0, :, :, :]
outputs_img_features = layer_features[1, :, :, :]
ct_loss += content_loss(content_img_features, outputs_img_features)

# style loss
sl_loss_temp = K.variable(0.)
for layer_name in style_feature_layers:
    layer_features = vgg16_outputs_dict[layer_name]
    outputs_img_features = layer_features[1, :, :, :]
    style_img_features = layer_features[2, :, :, :]
    sl = style_loss(style_img_features, outputs_img_features)
    sl_loss_temp += (alpha / len(style_feature_layers)) * sl
sl_loss = sl_loss_temp

# combine loss
loss = ct_loss + sl_loss

# write in summary
tf.summary.scalar('content_loss', ct_loss)
tf.summary.scalar("style_loss", sl_loss)
tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)

# optimization
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001,
                                  beta1=0.9,
                                  beta2=0.999,
                                  epsilon=1e-08).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    # Merge all the summaries and write them out to /tmp/mnist_logs (by default)
    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs/gen_model_v2',
                                         sess.graph)

    # initialize all variables
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    # get training image
    ct_img_name = [x for x in os.listdir(coco_img_path) if x.endswith(".jpg")]
    ct_img_num = len(ct_img_name)
    print("content image number: ", ct_img_num)
    sl_img_name = [x for x in os.listdir(sl_img_path) if x.endswith(".jpg")]
    sl_img_num = len(sl_img_name)
    print("style image number: ", sl_img_num)

    # start training
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(1):
        itr = 0
        for ct_name in ct_img_name:
            if itr > 10:  # used to train a small sample of ms coco
                break
            sl_name = sl_img_name[itr % sl_img_num]
            _, loss_val, summary = sess.run([train_op, loss, merged],
                                   feed_dict={content_img: preprocess_image(coco_img_path + ct_name, height, width),
                                              style_img: preprocess_image(sl_img_path + sl_name, height, width)})
            train_writer.add_summary(summary, itr * (i+1))
            print('iteration', itr, 'loss =', loss_val)
            itr += 1
    end_time = time.time()
    print('Training completed in %ds' % (end_time - start_time))

    # save model
    main_model.save('./models/gen_model_v2_1.h5')

    # use images to test
    test_ct_img_path = './images/content/train-1.jpg'
    test_ct_img = preprocess_image(test_ct_img_path, height, width)
    test_sl_img_path = './images/style/starry_night.jpg'
    test_sl_img = preprocess_image(test_ct_img_path, height, width)

    # feed test images into model
    output = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={content_img: test_ct_img, style_img: test_sl_img})
    output = deprocess_image(output)
    print('Output image shape:', output.shape[1:4])
    imsave('./images/autoencoder/test_v2_1.png', output[0])
```

and my loss function is defined as below:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf8 -*-
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

# the gram matrix of an image tensor (feature-wise outer product)


def gram_matrix(x):
    assert K.ndim(x) == 3
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        features = K.batch_flatten(x)   
    else:
        features = K.batch_flatten(K.permute_dimensions(x, (2, 0, 1)))
    gram = K.dot(features, K.transpose(features))
    return gram


def style_loss(featuremap_1, featuremap_2):
    assert K.ndim(featuremap_1) == 3
    assert K.ndim(featuremap_2) == 3
    g1 = gram_matrix(featuremap_1)
    g2 = gram_matrix(featuremap_2)
    channels = 3
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        size = featuremap_1.shape[1] * featuremap_1[2]   
    else:
        size = K.shape(featuremap_1)[0] * K.shape(featuremap_1)[1]
    size = K.cast(size, tf.float32)
    return K.sum(K.square(g1 - g2)) / (4. * (channels ** 2) * (size ** 2))


def content_loss(base, combination):
    return K.sum(K.square(combination - base))
```

So, you can see my loss value is squared using K.square(). How can it be a negative value?

This is the result of my code, that the loss decrease sharply, which seems impossible.
[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You're starting with a `ct_loss` as a variable. Just set it to the content loss.

```
ct_loss = content_loss(content_img_features, outputs_img_features)
```

Comment: Hey Jack, I modified my code as you said, but it seems doesn't work. The result doesn't change anymore.

Comment: If you run `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)` do you get anything?

Comment: @DomJack is right. Note that `sl_loss_temp = K.variable(0.)` should also be replaced. You could use `tf.zeros` instead.

Comment: @GeertH Thank U Geert. This time loss is not negative, however, I meet another problem, my style_loss is 0 constantly, when I observe it in Tensorboard,which doesn't make sense. By the way, I also wonder why it can't be a tf.variable.

Comment: You can't use `sl_loss_temp = K.variable(0.)` because it will be interpreted as a parameter of your model. So minimizing the loss becomes trivial: it will make the variable as small as possible. Resulting in a very low loss.

The loss stays zero because due to this statement: `sl_loss = sl_loss_temp
` which undos all previous calculation.

Comment: @GeertH Thank U very much for your kind answer!